# I can't install json module

Tags: python, json, pip, package

Whenever I try to install a package I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement json (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for json
```

Comment: Could you give us a bit more info? What exactly did you run? What environment are you using?

Comment: json is a built-in module, no need to install

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Install Dependencies into directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883925/python-install-dependencies-into-directory)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Could+not+find+a+version+that+satisfies+the+requirement+json

Comment: Worth mentioning that if you put `json` into your requirements.txt it will throw an error when installing

Answer (score 18):

Python has a built-in JSON module. If that's what you're looking for.
Just import in your script or shell:

```
import json
```

Answer (score 2):

As Bruno mentioned, python already has a build in JSON module so there is no value in installing a different package. Assuming that is what you are looking for.

Open up your shell and type:

```
import json
```

If you want more information on exactly how this is done check out this python doc:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html